# Creating instances for a linked list class in C++

Tags: c++, class, linked-list

I am currently learning C++ linked list and I hit this piece of code from the textbook.I have trouble understanding this:

```
const string& e
```

I am trying to write some instances for this class in my main function to see how things works but don't know how. 
For example, I want to add 3, 5, 7 to the list and add 1 to the front of the list, than delete 7 from the list.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::string;
using namespace std;



class StringNode {                      // a node in a list of strings
private:
  string elem;                              // element value
  StringNode* next;                     // next item in the list

  friend class StringLinkedList;                // provide StringLinkedList 
                                                // access
};

class StringLinkedList {                    // a linked list of strings
public:
  StringLinkedList();                       // empty list constructor
  ~StringLinkedList();                          // destructor
  bool empty() const;                       // is list empty?
  const string& front() const;                      // get front element
  void addFront(const string& e);               // add to front of list
  void removeFront();                       // remove front item list
private:
  StringNode* head;                     // pointer to the head of list
};

StringLinkedList::StringLinkedList()            // constructor
  : head(NULL) { }

StringLinkedList::~StringLinkedList()           // destructor
  { while (!empty()) removeFront(); }

bool StringLinkedList::empty() const            // is list empty?
  { return head == NULL; }

const string& StringLinkedList::front() const       // get front element
  { return head->elem; }



void StringLinkedList::addFront(const string& e) {  // add to front of list
  StringNode* v = new StringNode;           // create new node
  v->elem = e;                          // store data
  v->next = head;                   // head now follows v
  head = v;                     // v is now the head
}



void StringLinkedList::removeFront() {              // remove front item
  StringNode* old = head;               // save current head
  head = old->next;                 // skip over old head
  delete old;                       // delete the old head
}
```

Comment: `const string &e` is a reference to a constant (read-only) string. It is used in e.g. `void addFront(const string& e);` to provide a reference to an existing string (which can be used for read access only) without copying the string (contents) itself. (This doesn't prevent `addFront()` from making a copy from `e` to `v->elem`.)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to look for a duplicate which explains how `C++` uses call-by-value.

In C++ a function parameter of type `T` will make a copy of the object before the function is called.

```
int myFunction( int value )
{
     value = value + 1;
}

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    int elem = 6;
    myFunction( elem );
    printf( "%d\n", elem ); // elem = 6;
}
```

In the above example a copy is made of the `int` value, which is sent to `myFunction`, and the copy is incremented.

This may not be what is wanted, and we can change the result to 7, by modifying `myFunction` to take a reference to the value.  This is done by using the '&' to describe a reference value.

```
int myFunction( int & value )
{
     value = value + 1;
}

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    int elem = 6;
    myFunction( elem );
    printf( "%d\n", elem ); // elem = 7;
}
```

In the above case, no copy is made, and elem gets updated.

There are 2 main reasons you pass references to a function

1. To allow the value (or object) to be updated.
2. To avoid the cost of copying the value.

In your quoted example the second case is why the `const string &` is used (reference to string object).  `std::string`, has costs to construct and destroy, so by sending a reference to avoid this, is more efficient.

To compliment this usage, the reference, is usually made `const` to convince the compiler that the value should not be changed.